# highlight (soul package) in figure caption generates error

Tags: captions, soul

I have a short command that allows me to highlight some text for internal review purposes. Unfortunately, when I use it in a Caption of a figure it gives me the following error.

```
Argument of \@textcolor has an extra }. ...MA{This is my comment} More caption text.}
Paragraph ended before \@textcolor was complete. ...MA{This is my comment} More caption text.}
```

Here is my MWE that generates that error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}           % For figures and stuff
\usepackage{xcolor}             % Colors
\usepackage{soul}               % Highlight with \hl

%Colored comments for internal review purposes
\newcommand{\MA}[1]{{\sethlcolor{lime}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Highlighting \MA{in the text} works fine.


\begin{figure}[htbp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
    \caption{This is a picture. \MA{This is my comment} More caption text.}
    \label{fig:Examplefigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macro `\MA` is not robust for moving arguments like figure captions.

- Use `\protect`:

  ```
  \protect\MA{...}
  ```
- Or define a robust command:

  ```
  \newcommand{\MA}{}% Error, if \MA is already defined.
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\MA}[1]{{\sethlcolor{lime}\hl{#1}}}
  ```